How to get the current model in relationship manager filament
Currently I am working on a project with filament version 2, I have 3 tables like the following



users
profiles
skills




id
id
id


name
user_id
profile_id



image
name



in App\Models\User I have a relationship like this
public function profile(): HasOne
{
   return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'user_id');
}

public function skills(): HasManyThrough
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Skill::class, Profile::class);
}

I have App\Filament\Resources\UserResource\RelationManagers\SkillRelationManager. In this file there is a SkillRelationManager class which has a static method form as follows
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\Hidden::make('profile_id')
                ->default(fn(User $user) => $user->profile->id),

            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                ->required(),
        ]);
}

I want to get the profile ID of the user I am editing. I have tried using a callback as below, but the callback actually creates a new user instance instead of retrieving the user data that I am editing.
Forms\Components\Hidden::make('profile_id')
    ->default(fn(User $user) => $user->profile->id)

So how do I get the current user that I am editing

In FilamentPHP, in order to get the current model/record, you need to use the $record variable:
Forms\Components\Hidden::make('profile_id')
    ->default(fn(User $record) => $record->profile->id)

In FilamentPHP, the $record variable is indeed injected automatically when working with forms or form components within the context of editing or displaying a model instance. This injection happens behind the scenes by FilamentPHP's framework.
Docs

In FilamentPHP, in order to get the owner record, you need to use the $livewire or $this but in you case you can use $livewire:
 ->default(function ($livewire) {
      $ownerRecord = $livewire->ownerRecord
 };
)

